# Деплой приложения на Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku

Не могу уже который час задеплоить приложение на heroku, не могу понять в чем проблема.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

файлик `package.json`

```
{
  "name": "stop-schedule",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node  ./bin/www"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.20.0",
    "bootstrap-autocomplete": "^2.3.7",
    "bootstrap4-jade": "^1.0.0-dev",
    "cookie-parser": "~1.4.4",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "debug": "~2.6.9",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.1",
    "express": "~4.16.1",
    "http-errors": "~1.6.3",
    "jade": "~1.11.0",
    "jade-bootstrap": "^1.0.14",
    "morgan": "~1.9.1",
    "mysql": "^2.18.1",
    "mysqlconnector": "^2.0.0"
  },
  "main": "app.js"
}
```

файлик `www`

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */

var app = require('../app');
var debug = require('debug')('stop-schedule:server');
var http = require('http');

// const routes = require(index.js)
/**
 * Get port from environment and store in Express.
 */

var port = normalizePort(process.env.PORT || '3000');
app.set('port', port);

/**
 * Create HTTP server.
 */

var server = http.createServer(app);

/**
 * Listen on provided port, on all network interfaces.
 */

server.listen(port);
server.on('error', onError);
server.on('listening', onListening);

/**
 * Normalize a port into a number, string, or false.
 */

function normalizePort(val) {
  var port = parseInt(val, 10);

  if (isNaN(port)) {
    // named pipe
    return val;
  }

  if (port >= 0) {
    // port number
    return port;
  }

  return false;
}

/**
 * Event listener for HTTP server "error" event.
 */

function onError(error) {
  if (error.syscall !== 'listen') {
    throw error;
  }

  var bind = typeof port === 'string'
    ? 'Pipe ' + port
    : 'Port ' + port;

  // handle specific listen errors with friendly messages
  switch (error.code) {
    case 'EACCES':
      console.error(bind + ' requires elevated privileges');
      process.exit(1);
      break;
    case 'EADDRINUSE':
      console.error(bind + ' is already in use');
      process.exit(1);
      break;
    default:
      throw error;
  }
}

/**
 * Event listener for HTTP server "listening" event.
 */

function onListening() {
  var addr = server.address();
  var bind = typeof addr === 'string'
    ? 'pipe ' + addr
    : 'port ' + addr.port;
  debug('Listening on ' + bind);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка была в импорте, я неправильно подключал mysqlconector. mysqlConector c- большая, а надо маленькая.